# Angular2: when does property binding happen?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm just starting with Angular2, reading the official docs. However, I have not found specific details about how and when the binding happens, and things don't seem to work as I expected.

I have a simple child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dummy',
  template: `
    <div>{{data}}</div>
  `
})
export class Dummy {
  @Input() data;

}
```

and a root component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <dummy [data]="data"></dummy>
  `
})
export class MainComponent {
    data: string = "initial text";

    ngOnInit() {
      setTimeout(this.initData, 5000);
    }

    initData() {
      this.data = "new text";
    }
}
```

I would expect the text shown by the child component to change after 5 seconds, however it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Does the documentation explain when and under what conditions bound values are initialized and updated?

Comment: Check the article about [change detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html). For your example you need to ask angular to check changes. To do this inject **ChangeDetectorRef** and call **markForChanges()** method. Read the article for more info.

Comment: @BuDen: thanks!! Do you know where in the official docs it described change detection?

Comment: you can check docs for [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) it has few examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're losing context of `this`. at the time when `setTimeout` callback runs, `this` doesn't point to the component anymore. you might want to check a bit about javascript `this problem`.

try:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
      this.data = "new text";
 },5000);
```

Comment: @blue_note, this answer is correct, see plunkr example i created, https://plnkr.co/edit/AoTI8qMxtJs4FUXTBKgW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the OnInit interface and make your component implement it.

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

And then

`export class MainComponent implements OnInit { ... }`

Comment: However, that's not the problem. The interface it only used for type checking, the function `ngOnInit` is called regardless